# How to Send Images to Backend API more than 1mb in nextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

I'm trying to make my portfolio using NextJS and in creating Project Functionality I'm converting the images to base64 and sending them to API to upload them on Cloudinary and everything is good while the total size of the request is less than 1MB but when it's more than that I receive an error 413 that the Size must be less than 1MB.
what should I do?

Comment: As alternative, you could also [upload directly from the browser (client-side)](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_rest_api). This method would allow you to post your file directly to your Media Library account, see the [sample implementation here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#code_explorer_upload_multiple_files_using_a_form_unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

I Used an alternative solution by Uploading the Images from the Client Side and It works

I Used Cloudinary as a Database for my Images and used Upload from clientside you can read more about it here and customize it as you want
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_image_and_video_upload

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm sorry for being late but I update the answer for more details you can contact me at facebook
https://www.facebook.com/A.sni9er/